# regex to replace regex

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have this regex for getting strings in Python code:

```
x1 = re.compile('''((?P<unicode>u?)(?P<c1>'|")(?P<data>.+?)(?P<c2>'|"))''')
```

I want to extract the `data` and `c1`,`c2` parts of this regex to make a replace string (if `c1 == c2`)
Something like:

```
repl = "u<c1><data><c2>"
```

How can I do this??
Is that possible in one line or by using `re.sub`?

**UPDATE**:
My new code:

```py
x1 = re.compile('''(?P<unicode>u?)(?P<c>'|")(?P<data>.*?)(?P=c)''')
def repl(match):
    if '#' in match.string:
        ### Confused
    return "u%(c)s%(data)s%(c)s" % m.groupdict()

fcode = '\n'.join([re.sub(x1,repl,i) for i in scode.splitlines()])
```

Here, I am having problems to determine how to not change strings in comments, what do I have to do to ignore the comments??

Comment: Can this be used: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#text-munging ?

Comment: @MortenJensen Yes.. But please elaborate on it if you plan to answer using that...

Comment: I'm guessing what you want is to make code works under 3.3 and 2.x. Maybe 2to3 is a good choice. If you are not against using it, I will update my solution.

Comment: @Kabie You haven't updated for some time now, guess you were waiting for my OK...

Comment: I was waiting for you update your real question.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a pattern:

```
pattern = r'''(?P<unicode>u?)(?P<c>'|")(?P<data>.*?)(?P=c)''' # did a little tweak
```

Match a string:

```
m = re.search(pattern, "print('hello')")
```

What you got:

```
>>> m.groups()
('', '"', 'hello')
>>> m.groupdict()
{'c': '"', 'unicode': '', 'data': 'hello'}
```

Now you can do whatever you want with these:

```
>>> 'u{c}{data}{c}'.format_map(m.groupdict())
'u"hello"'
```

Maybe you are using Python 2.x:

```
>>> 'u{c}{data}{c}'.format(**m.groupdict())
'u"hello"'
```

Or even you like old `%`

```
>>> "u%(c)s%(data)s%(c)s" % m.groupdict()
'u"hello"'
```

**Edited**:

The regex solution can't handle some situations correctly.

So I used a `2to3` hack(it's actually 3to2, and still can't solve everything):

```
cd /usr/lib/python3.3/lib2to3/fixes/
cp fix_unicode.py fix_unicode33.py
```

Edit `fix_unicode33.py`

```
-_literal_re = re.compile(r"[uU][rR]?[\'\"]")
+_literal_re = re.compile(r"[rR]?[\'\"]")

-class FixUnicode(fixer_base.BaseFix):
+class FixUnicode33(fixer_base.BaseFix):

-                new.value = new.value[1:]
+                new.value = 'u' + new.value
```

Now `2to3 --list | grep unicode33` should output `unicode33`

Then you can run `2to3 -f unicode33 py3files.py`.

Remember to remove `fix_unicode33.py` after

**NOTE**: In Python3 `ur"string"` throws `SyntaxError`. The logic here is simple, modify it to reach your goal.

Comment: Thanks but I was just about to post an edit, on how to change my function (which I will post) to not edit comments...

Comment: I don't understand what your edit means.. What's with 2to3/3to2 ??

Comment: @Schoolboy: that's to answer another question which you didn't ask but I assumed - add `u` prefix to strings in a python source file.

Answer (score 0):

The long code I ended up with.

```py
x1 = re.compile('''(?P<unicode>u?)(?P<c>'|")(?P<data>.*?)(?P=c)''')

def in_string(text,index):
    curr,in_l,in_str,level = '',0,False,[]

    for c in text[:index+1]:
        if c == '"' or c == "'":
            if in_str and curr == c:
                instr = False
                curr = ''
                in_l -= 1
            else:
                instr = True
                curr = c
                in_l += 1
        level.append(in_l)
    return bool(level[index])

def repl(m):
    return "u%(c)s%(data)s%(c)s" % m.groupdict()

def handle_hashes(i):
    if i.count('#') == 1:
        n = i.find('#')
    else:
        n = get_hash_out_of_string(i)
    return re.sub(x1,repl,i[:n]) + i[n:]

def get_hash_out_of_string(i):
    n = i.find('#')
    curr = i[:]
    last = (len(i)-1)-''.join(list(reversed(i))).find('#')
    while in_string(curr,n) and n < last:
        curr = curr[:n]+' '+curr[n+1:]
        n = curr.find('#')
    return n
```